# Allow lambda to access particular s3 bucket in serverless config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless, amazon-policy

How can I allow specific lambda to access to a particular s3 bucket in the serverless.yml?

For example, I am porting file upload functionality to lambda by using serverless. To upload a file to a particular s3 bucket, I need to allow lambda to access to that s3 bucket. How can I do this in the serverless.yml?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [Serverless Framework - AWS Lambda Guide - IAM](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/):

> To add specific rights to this service-wide Role, define statements in `provider.iamRoleStatements` which will be merged into the generated policy.

```yaml
service: new-service
 
provider:
  name: aws
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            - 's3:ListBucket'
          Resource:
            Fn::Join:
              - ''
              - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                - Ref: ServerlessDeploymentBucket
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            - 's3:PutObject'
          Resource:
            Fn::Join:
              - ''
              - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                - Ref: ServerlessDeploymentBucket
                - '/*'
```

Comment: Yep. Thanks. So the "Ref" means the ref of the bucket where the application is deployed right? How can I get the ref of it?

Comment: It would either be a reference to a bucket created elsewhere in the template, or insert the ARN of an existing bucket (eg `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket`).

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: I had to add "    - '/*'   " underneath the Ref line. You'll see in the example from the serverless docs that are linked.

Comment: Ended up by setting `'arn:aws:s3:::${file(./s3config.json):bucketName}/*'`